# sed on linux and MacOS in Makefile

Tags: linux, macos, sed, makefile, bsd

I am writing a Makefile which is supposed to work on Linux and on MacOS systems. I make use of the `sed` program.
It turns out that BSD sed and gnu sed differ in a small but crucial detail. I cite from the man pages:

```
BSD:
-i extension ...

GNU:
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
```

So on the Mac I have to call

```
sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/' file.tmp
```

where the empty string after `-i` is necesary, while on the Linux machine I call

sed -i 's/foo/bar/' file.tmp

Here is the question:

**Is there a safe way to distinguish between the two OS's in the Makefile?**

I can of course have the user call `Makefile.mac` or `Makefile.linux`, but I would rather avoid this.

Comment: Feature test the `sed` command? Run something like `sed -i ext 's///' <<<input` and see if it succeeds or errors? That should succeed with bsd sed and fail on GNU sed I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safe way is to not use the `-i` option of `sed`. This option is an unportable extension and is not part of POSIX.

Comment: Learning something everyday... So I guess there is no way around temporary files...

Comment: You could also try to alter your script so `sed` filters incoming data as intended. Hard to say what the best idea is without seeing more of your Makefile (hint hint).

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using the `-i` at all by using code like this:

```
sed 's/foo/bar/' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

It will then write data to a tmp file `> tmp`
If no error occurs `&&` move tmp file back to original  `file`

You will get a temp file for some short time.
I am not sure if this will be slower than the  `-i` option.